# C++ signal does not get caught on QML side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-signals

I was checking [this example](https://www.wisol.ch/w/articles/2014-12-15-qt-signal-slots-qml-cpp/) and I cannot catch `Qt C++ signal` in `QML`. Here is my `UeSettings` class header:

```
#ifndef UESETTINGS_H
#define UESETTINGS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDateTime>

#include "uedefaults.h"
#include "models/ueprintersmodel.h"
#include "uetypes.h"

/**
 * @brief The UeSettings class
 */
class UeSettings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    /**
     * @brief m_ueServerAddress
     */
    QString m_ueServerAddress;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueServerPort
     */
    QString m_ueServerPort;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueDatabaseName
     */
    QString m_ueDatabaseName;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueDatabaseUsername
     */
    QString m_ueDatabaseUsername;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueDatabasePassword
     */
    QString m_ueDatabasePassword;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueHostname
     */
    QString m_ueHostname;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown
     */
    QString m_ueNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueDb
     */
    QSqlDatabase m_ueDb;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse
     */
    bool m_ueAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse;

    /**
     * @brief m_ueAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill
     */
    bool m_ueAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill;

    /**
     * @brief m_uePrintersModel
     */
    UePrintersModel* m_uePrintersModel;

    /**
     * @brief ueSetServerAddress
     * @param address
     */
    inline void ueSetServerAddress(const QString& address)
        { this->m_ueServerAddress=address; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetServerPort
     * @param port
     */
    inline void ueSetServerPort(const QString& port)
        { this->m_ueServerPort=port; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseName
     * @param dbName
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseName(const QString& dbName)
        { this->m_ueDatabaseName=dbName; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetDatabaseUsername
     * @param dbUsername
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabaseUsername(const QString& dbUsername)
        { this->m_ueDatabaseUsername=dbUsername; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetDatabasePassword
     * @param dbPassword
     */
    inline void ueSetDatabasePassword(const QString& dbPassword)
        { this->m_ueDatabasePassword=dbPassword; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown
     * @param topN
     */
    inline void ueSetNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown(const QString& topN)
        { this->m_ueNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown=topN; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetHostname
     * @param hostname
     */
    inline void ueSetHostname(const QString& hostname)
        { this->m_ueHostname=hostname; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse
     * @param automaticStockUpdate
     */
    inline void ueSetAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse(const bool& automaticStockUpdate)
        { this->m_ueAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse=automaticStockUpdate; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill
     * @param automaticLogoffWorkerAtBill
     */
    inline void ueSetAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill(const bool& automaticLogoffWorkerAtBill)
        { this->m_ueAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill=automaticLogoffWorkerAtBill; }

    /**
     * @brief uePrintersModel
     * @return
     */
    inline UePrintersModel* uePrintersModel() const
        { return this->m_uePrintersModel; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetPrintersModel
     * @param printersModel
     */
    inline void ueSetPrintersModel(UePrintersModel* const printersModel=0)
        { this->m_uePrintersModel=printersModel; }

    /**
     * @brief ueDatabase
     * @return
     */
    QSqlDatabase ueDatabase()
        { return this->m_ueDb; }

    /**
     * @brief ueSetDatabase
     * @param database
     */
    void ueSetDatabase(const QSqlDatabase& database)
        { this->m_ueDb=database; }

    /**
     * @brief ueCreateDatabase
     * @return true if settings database successfully created, otherwise false
     */
    bool ueCreateDatabase();

    /**
     * @brief ueDatabaseExists
     * @return true if settings database exists, otherwise false
     */
    bool ueDatabaseExists();

public:
    /**
     * @brief UeSettings
     * @param parent
     * @param printersModel
     */
    explicit UeSettings(QObject *parent = 0,
                        UePrintersModel* const printersModel=0);

    /**
     * @brief ~UeSettings
     */
    ~UeSettings();

    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueServerAddress() const
        { return this->m_ueServerAddress; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueServerPort() const
        { return this->m_ueServerPort; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDatabaseName() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabaseName; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDatabaseUsername() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabaseUsername; }
    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueDatabasePassword() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabasePassword; }

    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueHostname() const
        { return this->m_ueHostname; }

    Q_INVOKABLE inline bool ueAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirwstWarehouse() const
        { return this->m_ueAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse; }

    Q_INVOKABLE inline QString ueNumerOfTopSalesProducts() const
        { return this->m_ueNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown; }

    Q_INVOKABLE inline bool ueAutomaticLogoffWorkerAtBill() const
        { return this->m_ueAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill; }

    /**
     * @brief ueConnectToDatabase
     * @return true if connetion to database successfull, otherwise false
     */
    bool ueConnectToDatabase();

    /**
     * @brief ueSaveSettings
     * @param address
     * @param port
     * @param dbName
     * @param dbUsername
     * @param dbPassword
     * @param hostName
     * @param autoStockUpdate
     * @param topN
     * @param autoLogoffWorkerAtBill
     * @return true if setitngs were saved in database successfully, otherwise false
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE bool ueSaveSettings(const QString& address,
                                    const QString& port,
                                    const QString& dbName,
                                    const QString& dbUsername,
                                    const QString& dbPassword,
                                    const QString& hostName,
                                    const QString& autoStockUpdate,
                                    const QString& topN,
                                    const QString& autoLogoffWorkerAtBill/*,
                                    UeTypePrintersList* const printersList*/);
    /**
     * @brief ueLoadSettings
     * @return true if settings were loaded successfully, otherwise false
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE bool ueLoadSettings();

    /**
     * @brief ueTestConnection
     * @param address
     * @param port
     * @param dbName
     * @param dbUsername
     * @param dbPassword
     * @return true if successfully connected to database, otherwise false
     */
    Q_INVOKABLE bool ueTestConnection(const QString& address,
                                      const QString& port,
                                      const QString& dbName,
                                      const QString& dbUsername,
                                      const QString& dbPassword);

signals:
    /**
     * @brief ueSignalSettingsLoaded
     */
    void ueSignalSettingsLoaded();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalSettingsSaved
     */
    void ueSignalSettingsSaved();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalSettingsNotFound
     */
    void ueSignalSettingsNotFound();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalTestDatabaseConnectionOk
     */
    void ueSignalTestDatabaseConnectionOk();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalTestDatabaseConnectionFailed
     */
    void ueSignalTestDatabaseConnectionFailed();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated
     */
    void ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated();

    /**
     * @brief ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty
     */
    void ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty();
public slots:
};

#endif // UESETTINGS_H
```

and here is method, which fires signals `ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated()` and `ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty`:

```
bool UeSettings::ueCreateDatabase()
{
    bool result=false;
    bool connected=false;

    if(this->ueDatabase().isOpen())
    {
        connected=true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->ueConnectToDatabase())
        {
            connected=this->ueDatabase().open();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << this->ueDatabase().lastError().text();
        }   // if
    }   // if

    if(connected)
    {
        QSqlQuery queryCreateDatabase(this->ueDatabase());

        if(queryCreateDatabase.prepare(UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::UeCreateSettingsDatabase::QUERY_TURN_ON_FOREIGN_KEYS_SUPPORT))
        {
            if(queryCreateDatabase.exec())
            {
                if(queryCreateDatabase.prepare(UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::UeCreateSettingsDatabase::QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_SETTINGS))
                {
                    if(queryCreateDatabase.exec())
                    {
                        if(queryCreateDatabase.prepare(UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::UeCreateSettingsDatabase::QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_PRINTERS))
                        {
                            if(queryCreateDatabase.exec())
                            {
                                if(queryCreateDatabase.prepare(UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::UeCreateSettingsDatabase::QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_SCREEN))
                                {
                                    if(queryCreateDatabase.exec())
                                    {
                                        result=true;

                                        emit this->ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated();
                                        emit this->ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty();
                                    }   // if
                                }   // if
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                                         << queryCreateDatabase.lastError().text();
                            }   // if
                        }   // if
                        else
                        {
                            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                                     << queryCreateDatabase.lastQuery()
                                     << queryCreateDatabase.lastError().text();
                        }   // if
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                                 << queryCreateDatabase.lastError().text();
                    }   // if
                }
                else
                {
                    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                             << queryCreateDatabase.lastError().text();
                }   // if
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                         << queryCreateDatabase.lastError().text();
            }   // if
        }   // if
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // ueCreateDatabase
```

in lines *45* and *46*:

```
emit this->ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated();
emit this->ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty();
```

Now, the instance of object `UeSettings`, named `ueSettings` is created and exposed to `QML` in `main.cpp`:

```
UeBluetoothManager* ueBtManager=new UeBluetoothManager(qApp);
UePrintersModel* uePrintersModel=new UePrintersModel(qApp,
    ueBtManager);
UeSettings* ueSettings=new UeSettings(qApp,
    uePrintersModel);

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueBtManager",
    ueBtManager);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePrintersModel",
    uePrintersModel);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueSettings",
    ueSettings);
```

and I am trying to catch signals `ueSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated()` and `ueSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty()` in some `QML` file with:

```
Connections
{
    target: ueSettings

    onUeSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated:
    {
        ueStatusText.text=qsTr("Settings Database Created.");
    }   // onUeSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated
}   // Connections

Connections
{
    target: ueSettings

    onUeSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty:
    {
        ueStatusText.text=qsTr("Settings Database is Empty.");
    }   // onUeSignalSettingsDatabaseEmpty
}   // Connections
```

The signals from `C++` side get emmited, I've triple-checked with debugger and **ARE NOT** caught on `QML` side since the `text` property does not get changed. Why? The debug console does not fire up any warning or runtime errors at all (related to issue).

Comment: I do not have `UeSettings { id: ueSettings }` in my code, I expose this object to `QML` in `main.cpp:` `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueSettings", ueSettings);`

Comment: Why would I recreate the object in `QML` code? It does not make sense. I create it in `main.cpp` and I do not need recreate it in `QML`. The object is exposed to `QML` just like that one in mentioned example is and example works, my code does not. I have missed something tiny ...

Comment: How can we see that that context is available in QML you test with?

Comment: @AlexanderVX check [this example](https://www.wisol.ch/w/articles/2014-12-15-qt-signal-slots-qml-cpp).

Comment: Understood. Though I don't do such technique myself I once read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html But the question is how exactly you populate that context with QML?

Comment: Are you calling ueCreateDatabase() from the class constructor?

Comment: @talamaki not directly, `ueCreateDatabase()` is called from `ueConnectToDatabase()`, which is called from class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [talamaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4911665/talamaki) was right, signal is emmited before `Connections` object is ready to receive signal on `QML` side. I've managed to solve the issue by connecting to signal [QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#objectCreated)
to `UeSettings::ueSlotQMLFileLoaded()` slot and inside it I check the state of settings database instead of doing so in constructor:

```
void UeSettings::ueSlotQMLFileLoaded(QObject* object,
    const QUrl& url)
{
    if(!this->ueConnectToDatabase())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                 << this->ueDatabase().lastError().text();
    }   // if
}   // ueSlotQMLFileLoaded
```

The `QML` part now receives the signal. However, I still do no understand why the hell identical mechanism **IS WORKING** in [example](https://www.wisol.ch/w/articles/2014-12-15-qt-signal-slots-qml-cpp/).

Comment: I suppose the difference was that in your case you initiated signal sending from constructor, not after the C++ object was fully constructed. In the example: 1) C++ object fully created, 2) QML loaded 3) signal sent

Answer (score 2):

Probably, signal is emitted before `Connections` object is ready to receive the signal in QML. If you add a query method e.g.

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool UeSettings::isUeSignalSettingsDatabaseCreated()
```

it probably returns true when you call it from QML side.

If I was you I would use properties to follow the statuses. From QML, you can access the `Q_PROPERTY` by using the property name that is defined in the header file.

Comment: nice hint, however, I want **event driven** behaviour because I want to popup settings windows once database is created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun qMake, clean and rebuild, so that the signals are connected correctly. At least that is often the case for me if I have this problem.